# Point of symmetry in $y=\frac{9x+7}{3x+12}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I got this question to find point of symmetry in $$y=\frac{9x+7}{3x+12}$$

As it is, I am not able to see a way to do this. Plotting on google

[image]

we get that point of symmetry may be in second quadrant. Still how will we find it if we don't have graph at all?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is $x=-4$ the polstelle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let consider a translation of the origin in $(-4,3)$ that is

- $u=x+4\implies x=u-4$
- $y-3=v\implies y=v+3$

and we obtain

$$y=\frac{9x+7}{3x+12}\iff v+3=\frac{9(u-4)+7}{3(u-4)+12}\iff v=\frac{9u-29}{3u}
-3\iff v=\frac{-29}{3u}$$

Comment: And how we know that we translate it to that point.

Comment: that's the intersection of asymptotes, in this case it's a point of polar symmetry

Answer (score 3):

The point of symmetry is the point where the horizontal and vertical asymptotes intersect.

The vertical asymptote can be found by setting the denominator equal to zero.
\begin{align*}
3x + 12 & = 0\\
3x & = -12\\
x & = -4
\end{align*}

The horizontal asymptote is the value the function approaches as $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$. If we divide the numerator by the denominator, we get 
$$9x + 7 = 3(3x + 12) - 29 \implies \frac{9x + 7}{3x + 12} = 3 - \frac{29}{3x + 12}$$
The term 
$$-\frac{29}{3x + 12} \to 0$$
as $x \to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$.  Hence, the horizontal asymptote is $y = 3$.

Therefore, the point of symmetry is $(-4, 3)$.